# OpenGL Lighting

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to Figure out how to use the Lighting engine in OpenGL.
My aim is to simulate A torch in the Camera's direction.

```
gluLookAt(  x, y, z,
        x+lx, y+ly,  z+lz,
        0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);
GLfloat light_position[] = { x+1, y, z+1, 0.0f };
GLfloat light_direction[] = { x+lx,y+ly,z+lz};
GLfloat light_angle[] ={20};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,light_direction);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,light_angle);
```

But when i execute it, only a small amount of ambient light is shown, nothing like a Beam in a direction.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled `GL_LIGHTING` and `GL_LIGHT0` with `glEnable`?

Comment: Yes, and now i tried GLfloat light_position[] = { x+1, y, z+1, 100.0f };, now there's a light from the -infinte of the z - axis... eventhough  lightposition is position of the camera

Comment: Hmm.  I'm gonna take a guess that your `light_direction` vector is the problem, then.  If it's truly just a direction _vector_, it should just be `{lx, ly, lz}` (note that `gluLookAt` takes a _point_ as its second argument, and that's why you need to add in the point coordinates).  If that doesn't fix it, though, I'm at a loss...

Comment: Hmm well this fixes it only a bit, the direction s working now, but the position is still "weird".

Comment: I believe that the `w` coordinate of your position should be `1.0f`.  There's a passable explanation [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/518088-gllight--direction--gl_position-can-you-explain-me-this/), but the general rule is that `w = 0` for vectors and `w = 1` for points.

Comment: Good catch. If `w==0`, then the light is a directional light of direction `xyz`. If `w!=0`, then the light has a position `[x,y,z,w]` = `[x/w, y/w, z/w]`.

Comment: @AndiFaust you could also try to experiment with GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, try 1, 2 or 4...

Comment: Also remember that both the light position and direction are affected by current modelview matrix, so specify them in object space. If your modelview matrix has the camera transformation (via `gluLookAt`), then probably you'd want to set the light position to `{0,0,0}` because you're now in the camera's coordinate system. The same goes for the direction.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL lights don't draw "beams", they only [affect how geometry is lit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model).

Visible "light beams" (like what you see when you have a strong directional light in dense air like fog or light clouds) are often called "light shafts". Is this the kind of effect you'd like to see?

http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/Mitchell_LightShafts.pdf

---

Also remember that old OpenGL 1 lighting model is per-vertex. If you're directing your light onto a flat surface, then either..

- subdivide the surface to have enough vertices for the light shape to be visible well,
- implement a per-pixel shading in a shader.